# PSCX Invoke-BatchFile afterlife

Tags: powershell

I'm still rather new to PowerShell, so bear with me. Why does the PowerShell console behave wierdly after using the Invoke-BatchFile cmdlet of PSCX?

```
C:\> cd
C:\> cd .\Kellekek
C:\Kellekek> cd ..
C:\>
C:\> Invoke-BatchFile 'C:\Kellekek\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat' amd64
C:\> cd

     # Directory Stack:
   --- ----------------
->   0 C:\

C:\> cd .\Kellekek
C:\Kellekek
C:\Kellekek> cd ..
C:\
C:\>
```

Before using the cmdlet everything seems to work fine. After using it, seems as if another utility would take over 'cd' and return powershell objects on every invocation, which I see as either a solo extra line (already quite annoying), or something that looks almost as a snippet of 'ls'.

Why is this? Is there a way to get rid of this behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Máté

Comment: Hey, if it were like the `ls` behavior it would have put "two" blank lines before and after the output.  :-)  BTW why do  you execute cd by itself?  Is it to see the current directory or some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a command from a module imports that module -- so when you run that command, you imported the PSCX module.

PSCX changes the "CD" alias to point at their "Set-LocationEx" command, which automatically tracks location history so you can easily navigate to previous locations. When you call Set-LocationEx with no parameters, they show you the stack (why *else* would you run CD with no parameters, anyway?)

Side note, for importing environment changes from a batch files into PowerShell, I use this script from PoshCode instead: http://poshcode.org/3547

P.S.: They also (by default) use Write-Host to echo your new location.  You can turn that behavior off by setting the preference variable:

```
$Pscx:Preferences.CD_EchoNewLocation = $False
```

Since everyone knows that using [write-host is considered harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), right? Using it to write the directory path out when I've not asked for a -Passthru is awfully strange, so you could vote for [this bug](https://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/35401) ;-)

P.P.S.: Unfortunately, although PSCX created a preferences drive, PSCX does not seem to persist preference changes (I'm not sure why, but I'll see if I can find out). Anyway, to make your preferences known, you need to edit a copy of the `Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1` **and** then pass the path to that file in as an `-Arg` when you import the PSCX module (meaning you can't rely on automatic importing).  Obviously that's a pain:

```
Import-Module Pscx -Arg ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1
```

Comment: It is not the parameter-less version that I mind. The part that bugs me, is that there are extra lines after every directory change, as if it printed to console the dir I just changed to.

Comment: Oh, you're right. They are killing kittens by default. I forgot. I will add that information to my answer, because putting it here is hopeless ;-)

Comment: Forgive my noobish question: how do I make those preferences actually take effect? I set the CD_echo stuff, and set default editor to vim.exe. Even if I invoke the .ps1 file explicitly (before/after module import don't matter), or even if I call it from my profile file, or import the module from there, it does nothing.

Comment: CD_EchoNewLocation was a user request that I added later.  I probably should never have made it the default since a lot of folks display current dir in either their prompt or the main title bar.  As for using write-host, only a sith lord deals in absolutes.  :-)  Seriously, the intent is only for the interactive user to see the new directory they've cd'd to.  I didn't want this extraneous output to appear script logs - hence the use of write-host.  BTW if you did want that or pass thru for other reasons, well that's what -PassThru is for.

Comment: I just discovered the Invoke-Batchfile ".../vcvarsall.bat amd64" messes up my environmental variables. Variables with my name "MátéFerenc" such as my home directory are wiped to ASCII mumbo-jumbo. How does this happen? I didn't find anything in vcvars that looked to me as character encoding change.

Comment: You should ask that in a new question, @Meteorhead, or better yet, as a bug on CodePlex: they screwed up by putting it in a file (from CMD) -- THAT sets the encoding. You can try my version from PoshCode: http://poshcode.org/3547

Answer (score 0):

"Displaying" the directory stack is a basic function of the PSCX cd replacement.  If you don't want to use the replacement CD functionality you can configure the Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1 file to not to load it by setting this section like so:

```
ModulesToImport = @{
    CD = $false
    ...
```

And then passing in the path to the file like so when importing the module:

```
Import-Module Pscx -Arg $home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1
```

Unfortunately you will need to load Pscx explicitly first.  If you use PowerShell's auto-loading module feature, PSCX will always get loaded with default values.

However, before you get rid of CD I encourage to play around by cd to a bunch of different directories and then try `cd -` to back one directory in your cd history and then try `cd +` to move forward.  Now when you execute `cd` you can see the complete history.  Try executing `cd 1` to take you to the directory specified in slot 1.